# How do you match a MultiIndex dataframe column to a simple dataframe and multiply together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a multi-index dataframe and a matching simple dataframe how do you match on the first column index and multiply?

Example: How do you you take these two dataframes...

```
a1 |     blue     |     fish
a2 | a    b    c  |  d    e    f
--------------------------------
0  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
1  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1
2  | 1    1    1  |  1    1    1

    blue   fish
0   2      3
1   2      3
2   2      3
```

...and multiply all the blues and fishes together to end up with this?

```
a1 |     blue     |     fish
a2 | a    b    c  |  d    e    f
--------------------------------
0  | 2    2    2  |  3    3    3
1  | 2    2    2  |  3    3    3
2  | 2    2    2  |  3    3    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with parameter `level=0`:

```
df = df1.mul(df2, level=0)
print (df)
a1 blue       fish      
a2    a  b  c    d  e  f
0     2  2  2    3  3  3
1     2  2  2    3  3  3
2     2  2  2    3  3  3
```